# integrationTestCompile gradle dependency ignored

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, integration-testing

Following a few blog posts I tried to create a separate source folder for integration testing in gradle. I wanted also to add some additinal (arquillian) dependencies to my integrationTest task, but the integrationTestCompile seems to be ignored and I get a compilation error with the additional dependecy not resolved. When I change the dependecy to testCompile it works fine. Why is that so and how to change it? My simple test class:

```
//compilation fails with  [Static type checking] - The variable [ArquillianSputnik] is undeclared
@TypeChecked
@RunWith(ArquillianSputnik)
class TestSpec extends Specification {


}
```

and gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'war'

war.dependsOn 'native2ascii'

task native2ascii << {

    ant.delete() {
        fileset(dir: "${processResources.destinationDir}") {
            include(name: '*.properties')
        }
    }
    ant.native2ascii(src: 'src/main/resources/',
            dest: "${processResources.destinationDir}",
            includes: '**/*.properties',
            encoding: 'UTF-8')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    mavenLocal()
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs += ["src/main/java"]

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        groovy.srcDir file('src/integration-test/groovy')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testCompile
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath + configurations.testRuntime
    }
}

dependencies {
    //(...) non-test dependencies cut out for clarity

    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
    testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'
    testCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2'

    //when integrationTestCompile is changed to testCompile the compilation works and the test is executed
    integrationTestCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.spock:arquillian-spock-container:1.0.0.Beta3'
    integrationTestCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.graphene:graphene-webdriver:2.0.3.Final'
    integrationTestCompile 'org.jboss.as:jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed:7.2.0.Final'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: 'test') {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

}

check.dependsOn 'integrationTest'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you want to **add** to the compile and runtime classpaths rather than replace them. This really just means using the `+=` operator rather than the `=` one. Additionally, you really only want to add the other sourcesets output, we'll deal with configurations separately.

```
compileClasspath += sourcesets.main.output + sourcesets.test.output
runtimeClasspath += sourcesets.main.output + sourcesets.test.output
```

Next, we'll want to configure our integration test configurations. Usually, this just means making them extend the test and compile ones so that they contain all those dependencies as well.

```
configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem integration test cases with RestAssure. But, still facing the problem while running test cases `error: package io.restassured does not exist
import io.restassured.RestAssured;`